# Image Slider plugin which hovers on the Preview Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am in search of a slider in which the slider should hover on the preview image itself. I searched in google but they are not available for free of cost. Any free plugins? Please post the link.
I have to get a slider same as the below image.[image: Hovering Image Slider]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Online there are plenty of sliders and is fairly easy to create your own. I put the link of one that I really like and that you can customize to your liking.

http://fotorama.io/

Take a look to customize link-> http://fotorama.io/customize/

Comment: Hey thanks!!! This is what I want exactly. Can u tell me another link for Panorama view with click event. http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_panorama_equirectangular . This is the link for panorama example. I need such a slider with a thumbnail slider same like the one in the link you posted